# How to pre-fill client id and Authorization fields in React Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have a react Swagger UI component (swagger-ui-react) that I use to render open api specifications on my website.

I would like to have the client id and authorisation fields pre-filled with values I supply, so the user does not have to copy and paste them into these fields from somewhere else:

[Authorisation Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHDbr.png)

[Client id Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74kvr.png)